# Ajax Post request always run error function although curl to the same url works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, curl

I am using ajax's post method to get a json result back from the server. But when I click the button on my HTML page, the ajax function always run the error function that is, it always shows the alert saying "error". I am pasting my HTML body here for your review.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Form</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="header">

        </div>
        <div id="form">
            <table style="display:inline-block">
                <tr>
                    <td>Select a user:</td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="SelectUser" style="width:150px">
                            <option>User 1</option>
                            <option>User 2</option>
                            <option>User 3</option>
                            <option>User 4</option>
                            <option>User 5</option>
                            <option>User 6</option>
                            <option>User 7</option>
                            <option>User 8</option>
                            <option>User 9</option>
                            <option>User 10</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Action:</td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="SelectAction" style="width:150px">
                            <option>Buy</option>
                            <option>Sell
                            <option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quantity:</td>
                    <td><input id="txtQty" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right">
                        <input id="btnClear" type="button" value="Clear" style="width:100px" onclick="alert('Clear')" />
                        <input id="btnTrade" type="button" value="Trade" style="width:100px" onclick="getTrade()" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="data">
                <b>Recommendations</b>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function getTrade() {               
            $.ajax({                
                type: "POST",
                url:  "http://localhost:8000/queries.json/",    
                data: {user: "1", num: 4},
                success: function (resultData) {                    
                    alert("resultData");                 


                },
                error: function (xhr,thrownError){
                    alert("error");
                }
            }); 

        }
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the curl request (curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{ "user": "1", "num": 4 }' http://localhost:8000/queries.json) in my git shell, it works fine and return results as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: queries.json is a json file or controller method?

Comment: You're probably hitting the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: @ user2181397 - I'm not sure about the queries.json file. How do I know if its a controller?

Comment: @SLaks - Would you explain what that is and how can I do this the right way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I debugged the problem using Firefox firebug, I came to know the details of the error which are :

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/queries.json/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Looks like I need to enable CORS on the client as well as on the server. This would solve the problem.

Thanks SLaks for pointing me in the right direction.